# Como gerar shortcode de resultado de busca de um sistema PHP em uma página PHP?

Tags: php, shortcode

Possuo um sistema em PHP que faz alguns cadastros e listagem de dados. Para explicar o que gostaria de implementar, vou simular alguns códigos abaixo:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect(localhost, root, 123456, bancoteste);
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from tabela");
$tr1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

for ($i=0;$i++;$i<$tr1)
{
  echo "Codigo aqui para exibição dos dados 
  ...";
}
```

Neste caso, gostaria de disponibilizar estes dados em uma página PHP de um outro site, de modo que não fosse necessário disponibilizar os dados de acesso do meu banco de dados. Ou em outras palavras, é possível gerar um shortcode do meu resultado de busca para exportar para uma página externa do PHP?

Exemplo de shortcode que pensei:

[www.site.com.br/15/resultado]

Ao incluir este shortcode em uma página php, carregaria os dados automaticamente.

Comment: você quer que o seu wordpress exiba dados de um banco de dados diferente do usado na instalação?

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta, pois não tinha ficado clara a minha explicação

Comment: Sim Luis, agora entendi, você precisa criar uma API e um Plugin para WP para que sua ideia funcione.

Comment: Os sites são em dominios diferentes?

Answer (score 2):

### Se estiverem todos no mesmo sites ou o mysql for acessível entre os sites

Você pode simplesmente criar uma função assim:

global.php:

```
<?php

function exibirDados(query)
{
    //Evita conectar multiplas vezes
    static $conexao;

    //Cache da resposta
    static $cache;

    if (isset($cache[$query])) {
        echo $cache[$query];
        return;
    }

    if (!$conexao) {
        $conexao = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
    }

    if (!$conexao) {
        echo "Erro ao se conectar com o MySQL:" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "numero: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "erro: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao, query);
    $tr1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    $resultado .= '';

    for ($i=0;$i++;$i<$tr1)
    {
      $resultado .= '..... formate aqui';
    }

    $cache[$query] = $resultado;

    echo $resultado;
```

E então no seu arquivo pode fazer algo assim:

```
<?php
require_once 'global.php';
?>

bla bla bla bla <?php exibirDados('SELECT * ....'); ?>
bla bla bla bla <?php exibirDados('SELECT * ....'); ?>
bla bla bla bla <?php exibirDados('SELECT * ....'); ?>
bla bla bla bla <?php exibirDados('SELECT * ....'); ?>
```

### Se forem sites diferentes

Note que ao fazer isso você terá que fazer mais "downloads", o que pode elevar o consumo da página, não o código em si, mas a ideia.

De qualquer se é o que deseja, você pode usar `preg_replace_callback` com `curl` e
no dominio que possui os dados faça uma página como:

- resultado.php

  ```
  <?php

  if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
      return '[pagina não definida]';
  }

  $pagina = intval($_GET['pagina']);

  if ($pagina < 1) {
      return '[pagina invalida]';
  }

  $conexao = mysqli_connect(localhost, root, 123456, bancoteste);

  $result = mysqli_query($conexao, "select id, coluna1, coluna2 from tabela LIMIT ..., ...");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo ...;
  }

  mysqli_free_result($row);
  ```

Então no domínio que vai receber os dados pode criar algo como:

- global.php:

  ```
  <?php

  function downloadData($url)
  {
      static $dados;

      //Cache de dados, para evitar multiplos downloads repetidos
      if ($dados[$url]) {
          return $dados[$url];
      }

      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

      $resposta = curl_exec($ch);

      if (!$resposta) {
          $dados[$url] = '[dados inacessives]';
      } else {
          $dados[$url] = $resposta;
      }

      curl_close($ch);

      $ch = null;

      return $resposta;
  }

  function buscaDados($entrada)
  {
      $replace = function($match) {
          return downloadData($match[1]);
      };

      return preg_replace_callback('#\[(http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/%\-_]+?)\]#', $replace, $entrada);
  }
  ```

Depois inclua o global.php na paginas que irá usar, deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php

require_once 'global.php';

echo buscaDados('bla bla bla [http://site1/15/resultado.php] bla bla bla [http://site2/14/busca.php]');
```

Claro que o preferível é você talvez usar um formato como JSON para tratar bem os dados e talvez usar um método de autenticação, mas isso é outra historia.

**Importante:** Nos sites que vai incluir você deve retornar apenas as partes importante e de preferencia que você tenha controle sobre todos site incluidos, se não tiver talvez tenha que usar http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php assim irá só reter a parte necessária.

> **Nota**: Talvez não sejam as melhores abordagens, recomendo pensar em talvez uma API ou alguma coisa em um estrutura de organização de projeto existente, como MVC, se souber usa-lo, se usar sem entender que o motivo é organizar, ou usar de qualquer maneira, também será um problema.
>
> As vezes reinventar a roda é legal, mas desde que bem projetado e com um bom tempo de teste para ter certeza que será útil colocar em produção.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma `API` em seu sistema `PHP` e um `plugin` para o Wordpress para que ele consuma os dados da sua `API`.

Comment: Isso era para ser uma resposta mesmo? Para mim me parece um comentário, pois está algo muito amplo e genérico.

Comment: @VictorStafusa você viu como foi marcado esta pergunta? entende minha resposta agora?